Is it possible to stop with a breakpoint at error OR warning during Matlab run with dbstop?
I use the commands:
dbstop if error

and
dbstop if warning

Is it possible to combine those conditions, to stop at either warning or error?
As far as I tried, the latter doesn't catch both.
Ideally, it would look something like: dbstop if (error || warning)

You just give both commands, one after the other, to stop at either condition. Each sets a breakpoint condition. You can have many, many different breakpoint conditions set up at the same time. That is why there's a dbclear all command.

Thanks, I just discovered that. You should have written that as an answer.

Apparently, dbstop if warning and dbstop if error are independent, and should be called separately.
Calling dbstatus shows their status, and they can be toggled independently.

You can also set the dbstop options (and see their current state) from the EDITOR tab of the ribbon bar

In older versions of MATLAB I believe this was in the dropdown menu under "Breakpoints" instead of "Run"
